# Styling custom field (or) lookup object in Salesforce related content (like contacts)

Tags: salesforce, visualforce, force.com

Is it possible to add styling to a custom field when displayed in a related list, such as the contact list under accounts?

The new field will be updated by an API, so it is just read-only and we want them as graphical as possible, like big red flags/boxes when there is an issue or nice and green when passed. The API can update a single field or an object if more data is needed.

We thought about even using a formula field to check the values and if x then wrap in code styling red etc. But we are new to Salesforce and there may be a clear way of doing this. The text value can even be an image if it really, really had to be.

Imagine seeing your normal contact list, then one extra column called 'Status' and that column being filled with red, green or yellow statuses for easy review.

For context, this will be added to a managed app, so when its packaged up and installed the column with the linked object/new field will appear as needed and be updated by the external resource / connected app part.

Is it easier to create a whole new list element? That replaces the standard contact list, then get that to enable with any different special items? We are not sure as we do not know enough.

We also want the same button link text items under the account detail and other aspects, but adding to the column data seems the hardest from a styling point of view?

Thanks,
Pete

Comment: For others reference I've just found this helpful comment on the Trailblazer community page, will test and report back. Any other ideas welcome!

... You may need to do something like this as a formula field, formula return type 'text':

`IMAGE( 
Case( your_picklist_field , 
"Unintested", "img/samples/light_red.gif", 
"Undecided","img/samples/light_yellow.gif", 
"Interested","img/samples/light_green.gif", 
"/s.gif"), 
"Status Color")`

Comment: Reference link with examples that may match use case: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=useful_advanced_formulas_image_links.htm&type=5

Comment: The above example has been confirmed as working, while its not adding styling, its using graphics which in this context is fine.